# How are values in UTXO's stored

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, haskell

Are values in UTXO's stored in a set manner for example if 50 Tokens with metadata and 50 tokens without metadata had the same Token Name and currency symbol and were to be handed out from a script 1 at a time would it be a 50% chance of getting a metadata Token or would it be based on a order in some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a misunderstanding here may lie in the fact that the metadata generally is attached to transactions and not directly to the tokens.

The way an NFT is connected to its metadata is by looking back at the minting transaction of a token *(the transaction that created the token in the first place)*. And by doing so there is no problem in moving the tokens around freely without loosing track of their metadata. See more on how its currently done here: https://cips.cardano.org/cips/cip25/#motivation.

However, if your question is not related to NFTs, for other *"fungible"* tokens *(technically similar, but with a quantity > 1)* I believe you can create a scenario, in which you cannot trace each token back to the original minting transaction and thus there is no such hard connection between a token and the initial tx metadata. You could for example create 50 tokens in a tx with metadata and later create 50 more of the same token in a tx without metadata and mix them up *(ie use both as inputs to a single tx)* so you can no longer strictly separate them.

Comment: Thank you so much this was very benificial

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you mean by the second part of your question. However, keep in mind that a UTXO is nothing more than the output of a previous transaction. This means that a single UTXO can contain an arbitrary amount of data (currently limited by the transaction size limit). **It can be a combination of many different tokens, as well as metadata**. The metadata is not necessarily token-specific, though it can be if that is its intended purpose.

Comment: Thank you for your response. What i meant by the second part of my question is are Tokens without "NFT" metadata differently by the The same token without metadata or would they be considered 1 of the same by a Plutus Script.

Comment: I’ve never seen anything about “metadata” in Plutus code. Relevant data is always attached to the datum in smart contracts afaik.